# Creating a conditional link in html apsx page

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, conditional-statements, hyperlink

I am trying to create a link in a user area of my website.

After logging in, the users info is passed to the allow access to specific areas of the site. What I would like to do is create an html link that is controlled by a conditional statement.

for example, after a user logs in, I want to check whether they have credentials to click on a link which will allow them to advance to something new.  If they don't have the credentials, the link will be blocked out or not appear at.

I am looking for a place to start on this task, any documentation or keywords would be helpful.  Also code samples would help greatly.

The page is an aspx page, with vb code behind.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Forms Authentication?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Creating a link? Authenticating a user? Displaying conditional content? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Displaying conditional content.  I can create the link (basic html) and authenticate the user.  But I am not sure what the html should look like, while using a conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply put your logic in the page load event.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="myHyperLink" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

**VB:**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If 1 = 1 Then
        myHyperLink.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**ASPX Embedded Logic:**

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="myHyperLink" runat="server" 
     Visible='<%# Eval("[Some Condition]") != null ? true : false %>'>
     </asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: seems simple enough, I will try and let you know.  Thanks.

Comment: What if I didn't want to use the code behind?  Is there away to use the condition within the html code itself?

Comment: @user630581, I'm not a fan of mixing UI code and business logic, but I've updated my post to answer your question. I'm assuming you were able to get my original example working?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help.  I respect and understand your view on mixing UI code and B-logic, but for the sake of learning and understanding it is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was already answered, but if you're using the built-in role management, I've always preferred doing things this way:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Some Protected Page" ... />
```

In code-behind:

```
HyperLink1.Visible = User.IsInRole("admin");
```